# Unbounded hierarchical routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'd like to use webapi to expose a hierarchical key-value data structure like this:

```
http://www.whatever.com/api/root/level1/level2/leveln
```

Is this possible with webapi? And if so, how?

Comment: Thanks, very helpful :D (question edited)

Answer (score 1):

WebApi can expose almost any URI you like - it comes down to how you configure the routes, and how you interpret the method arguments once they've been extracted from the URL.

To map an unbounded hierarchical route, I'd map everything after the `/api/root/` to a single variable, and then explicitly parse and interpret that method in custom logic in your controller, or a dedicated service.

The trick to having the match include forward slashes is to add a `*` at the start:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "KeyValueHierarchy",
    routeTemplate: "api/test/root/{*keyLevels}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Hierarchy" }
);
```

Then in the controller

```
public class HierarchyController : ApiController
{

    public IHttpActionResult Get(string keyLevels)
    {
        var keys = keyLevels.Split('/');

        // ... do stuff with your keys

        return Ok(keys);
    }

}
```

A quick test:

`GET /api/test/root/foo/5/bar/10/foobar`

returned:

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <string>foo</string>
  <string>5</string>
  <string>bar</string>
  <string>10</string>
  <string>foobar</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```